# Add Custom Scripts with Linux (Ubuntu)

Tags: azerothcore

I'm really enjoying Azerothcore, however I would like to add custom scripts to my server. I have found a guide on how to do that, but it is based on windows OS.

guide: http://www.ac-web.org/forums/showthread.php?145843-Trinity-How-to-add-a-c-script-to-your-core

Is there guides that are specific to Linux (Ubuntu)? Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

The procedure of adding a Script to AzerothCore on Linux is the same as adding it on Windows, the only difference is the way you (re)compile the project.

So you can add your Scripts just the way you would do on Windows, then recompile the project.

As the [official tutorial](https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/Installation#classic-installation) explains, you can just (re)compile your project by:

1. re-running the `cmake` command, for example:

```
cmake ../ -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$HOME/azeroth-server/ -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/bin/clang++ -DWITH_WARNINGS=1 -DTOOLS=0 -DSCRIPTS=1
```

2. re-running the `make` and `make install`

```
make -j 6;
make install
```

Then you're good to go.

However, AzerothCore offers a better alternative to just adding custom scripts: [**Modules**](https://www.azerothcore.org/wiki/The-Modular-Structure).

Modules offer the same features of Scripts, plus the ability to keep them completely detached from the main source code. So you can for example keep them in a separate repository.

Comment: of course ,you first edit whatever you want to edit and then recompile :)

Comment: Thanks for the help.

https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk/blob/master/src/server/scripts/Custom/README.md

I followed this guide, but im not sure about this part "2 - Add the script to ../ScriptLoader.cpp"

How do I save the changes to the C++ ../ScriptLoader.cpp

Comment: @AndrewQ you're welcome. Please accept my answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: sorry, I edited my comment. still having troubles, sorry

Comment: @AndrewQ just open that file with an editor, modify it and save the changes

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to do... of course you can always edit files via terminal using `nano` or `vim`